# Libgdx and Box2DLights - too bright + colors grayed out

Tags: colors, libgdx, box2d, lighting, brightness

I'm writing a game with LibGDX and Box2DLights for lighting.

The first problem is when my lights overlap each other. I have directional light on sun and point light on character. When they overlap output color is way too bright. 
I tried changing colors of lights but lowering these makes lights useless when there's only one light(too dark).

My second problem is the colors are a bit grayed out(see on screen).

**[Image showing my problems](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd7qd2o04k0fa8n/s1.jpg?dl=0)** - first screen is too bright, second is with only one light(grayed out), and third is without lights(this is how colors should look).

Any ideas how to overcome these problems?

## **PROBLEM SOLVED**

I asked my friend about it and it's all about setting diffuse lighting in RayHandler like this:

```
rayHandler.useDiffuseLight(true);
```

Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: You should write an answer and accept it just to mark this topic as solved :-)

Comment: Slight correction for anyone else confused -- it's `RayHandler.useDiffuseLight(true)` -- it's static.